# Error while connecting to oracle database from .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle10g

I am using System.data.oracleclient namespace and place that dll in reference of my project

and i am used connection string as

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xx.x.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)));uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;
```

while running the application i am getting response message as

```
OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.
```

i do not know where i got stuck...

Can any one provide me any guide lines to solve this problem.

i too goggled but did not get correct solution.

waiting for your valuable suggestions and comments

Update 1 :

the code i use is

```
   con = new OracleConnection(conStr);
                con.Open(); // connection must be openned for command
                query = "insert into table1 values ('ss');
                cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
               if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("insert sucess!");
                }
                con.Close();
```

My stack trace error was

```
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at oracleTest.Program.getconnection() in D:\oracle\oracletst[via-oracleclient]\oracletst\Program.cs:line 29
   at oracleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\oracle\oracletst[via-oracleclient]\oracletst\Program.cs:line 21
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I assume you mean this happens sporadically. If so the problem is most likely your connection/command management and not the connection string itself. post the code that shows how you are managing the connection/command. or if you are using an ORM how you are managing the context.

Comment: @JasonMeckley i updated check it

Answer (score 0):

2 things I see that could be causing the problem

1. you are not disposing the ado.net objects
2. `con` & `cmd` appear to be a shared variables.

try this and see if the problem continues.

```
using(var con = new OracleConnection(conStr))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    con.Open(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 values ('ss');
    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("insert sucess!");
    }
}
```

because we are using the `using` keyword it will automatically call con/cmd.Dispose() when the block is exited. Dispose() will automatically call Close().

**EDIT**
make sure your connection string is formatted properly. http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Comment: how does it not help? without more information we are just guessing at the problem.